# replacement pattern in python(re.sub())

Tags: python

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9HEG.png)

[image]

Can someone please explain the process of the following `re.sub()` to me.

I am thinking the process is as following:

look for a `"."` then look for a digit then look for another digit that is between `1` and `9`. Now I am lost. What is the question mark for? What does the `\d*` do? Why do we need to use raw string regex in this case?

Comment: `\1` denotes group 1

Comment: [Regex Cheat Sheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) ... [Python String Literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to understand the process, I can simply explain it to you. I don't know if this regular expression is doing what you want or not..

- At first, the `.` is a special character in regex which means any character. But, we here want to use the dot character. In regex, this can be done by using escaping character `\` like so `\.`. So, using `.` means any character and using `\.` means a dot.
- The `\d` represents any digit and acts exactly like [0-9]
- When you used `[1-9]`, by then you specified to get the numbers from 1 till 9 which means that zero is excluded.
- We can use the asterisk `*` to choose zero or more characters. Unlike + which is used to choose one or more characters. So, using `\d*` means any consecutive digits from `[0-9]` or none.
- The `?` is used to indicate using just one character or none. So, using `[1-9]?` means try to find just one digit between 1 and 9 **IF FOUND**.
- The Parenthesis `()` is used for grouping the whole regular expression in one output.

If you want to know more about regular expression, here is an awesome cheat sheet.
[image]

**NOTE:**

I think the regex you have written in the question is not correct. I think it should be as follows `(\d*\.\d\d[1-9]?)` to obtain the same result. I will try to explain this regular expression using this number `3.141500012`. `\d*\.` means find any number of digits that could be found before the dot which would match the `3.`. then after that `\d\d` matches two digits after the dot which are `14`. Finally, the `[1-9]?` matches any digit between 1 and 9 if found which matches `1` in our example.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. Your code makes sense, however when I tested it it didn't work or maybe I am doing something wrong.                                                                                               prices = ["3.141500002", "12.125", "51.500"]

for p in prices:
    print("Before -->", p)
    p = re.sub(r"(\d*\.\d\d[1-9]?)", r"\1", p)
    print("After -->", p)                                                                                                           It just prints the whole numbers without any modifications, is my implementation wrong?

Comment: Yup, I got it. You are using `re.sub`,  So, use this regex instead `(\d*\.\d\d[1-9]?).*`

Comment: Thank you, it worked.! I don't understand why though! this (\d*\.\d\d[1-9]?) made sense to me, but this (\d*\.\d\d[1-9]?).* doesn't. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @MohamedAlmahmood [accepting answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/202811)

Comment: If you want to use the first regex, you can write something like this:
`p = re.findall(r"(\d*\.\d\d[1-9]?)", p)[0]` instead of ` p = re.sub(r"(\d*\.\d\d[1-9]?)", r"\1", p)`

Comment: I don't understand. Why did we need to put .* at the end of this (\d*\.\d\d[1-9]?).* to make it work? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Sorry @MohamedAlmahmood for responding too late, I totally forgot. When we used the following regex `(\d*\.\d\d[1-9]?)` with `re.sub()` over a certain number like `3.141500002`, the function replaces the part `3.141` with itself which makes us feel like it did nothing. SO, I changed the regex to `(\d*\.\d\d[1-9]?).*` to match the whole number, then replace it with the first group which is `3.141`. And that doesn't happen with `re.find` because this function returns the number we want and doesn't replace anything from the original number